# EhCache key type

Tags: java, ehcache

In EhCache, when adding an element to the cache :

```
cache.put(new Element("key1", "value1"));

// Element constructors :
Element(Object key, Object value)
```

I see I can give an `Object` as the key index.

**How can I use this to have a "complex" key, composed of multiple int : `(userId,siteId,...)` instead of a string as an index ?**

Thanks

Comment: This is a great question.  How do you make a multi-dimensional key for a cache or a map. The answer below @Bozho is more or less correct except for the string concat.  You'd burn less time building the new object and it would most likely be smaller as you wouldn't have (rough estimate) nearly 5 string creations implicitly by that concatenation (userId to string, inline ":", concatenation of userId+":", siteId to string, new string concat of prev str + siteId str).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrap it in a new class:

```
public class CacheKey implements Serializable {
    private int userId;
    private int siteId;
    //override hashCode() and equals(..) using all the fields (use your IDE)
}
```

And then (assuming you have defined the appropriate constructor):

```
cache.put(new Element(new CacheKey(userId, siteId), value);
```

For simple cases you can use string concatenation:

```
cache.put(new Element(userId + ":" + siteId, value));
```

Comment: String concatenation is not the best for me because I need the lowest memory size possible (many many records). With `Serializable`, will I be able to have the lightest/shortest key possible ? How is EhCache going to use the Key object ? Thanks

Comment: the size will not be an issue, don't worry. ehcache will get the hash of the object (hence you should override hashcode with all the fields included)

Comment: Sorry to resurrect but is it necessary to implement `Serializable`? Would `Comparable<CacheKey>` be sufficient?

Comment: nope, the key gets transferred and stored, so it needs to be serializable